Animation stops on the parent view when a child view is active
I have a parent view which contains some buttons with an animation that makes them flow horizontally in an infinte scroll fashion. There is another button when clicked opens a sheet view, however when the sheet view is active the animation stops and remains stopped even if I close the sheet view.
Code structure: There is HomeView which contains SearchButtonView that shows the sheet and HomeBodyView which contains the animation (QueryChipsView)
Code:
HomeView
struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            // Header
            HeaderView()
            Spacer() // Push everything to the top
            Spacer()
            
            //Query chips and sign in button
            HomeBodyView()
            Spacer()
            Spacer()
            
            
            SearchButtonView()
        }
        
    }
}

SearchButtonView:
struct SearchButtonView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = SearchButtonViewVModel()
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            viewModel.showSearchSheet.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("Ask anything...")
                .font(.system(size: 16))
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                .foregroundColor(Color("FontColor"))
                .padding() // Adds internal padding to the text
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity) // Make the button take full width
                .background(Color(.systemGray6))
                .cornerRadius(30)
                .shadow(radius: 1)
        }
        .padding()// Horizontal padding around the button
        .sheet(isPresented: $viewModel.showSearchSheet) {
            // Content of the sheet
          
            SearchView(showSearchSheet: $viewModel.showSearchSheet)
        }
        
    }
}

HomeBodyView
struct HomeBodyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Image("butler_logo_light") // Replace with your image asset name
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(height: 110) // Adjust the height as needed
                            .padding(.bottom, 10)
            Text("Search for your restaurant")
                .font(.system(size: 20))
                .fontWeight(.regular)
                .foregroundStyle(Color("FontColor"))

            // View that contains animation
            QueryChipsView()
        }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 100)
            
    }
}

QueryChipsView
import SwiftUI

struct ButtonData: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    var text: String
}

struct QueryChipsView: View {
    let buttonData = [
        ["️ Did Edison invent the lightbulb?", "‍♂️ How do you ride a bike?"],
        ["⛷️ The best ski resorts in the Alps", "️ The greatest Super Bowl moments", " Best movies of all time"],
        [" The best boxing style", " The best dog breed for apartments","️ Top beach destinations"],
    ]
    

    var body: some View {
        
        // Apply the scrolling content as an overlay to a placeholder,
        // so that it is leading-aligned instead of center-aligned
        Color.clear
            .overlay(alignment: .leading) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    ForEach(Array(DummyData().restaurantButtonData.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { rowIndex, buttonItems in
                        ScrollingButtonRow(buttonItems: buttonItems)
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 200) // Constrain the height of the button area
    }
    
}

struct ScrollingButtonRow: View {
    let buttonItems: [String]
    let spacing: CGFloat = 14
    let baseSpeed: CGFloat = 50 // Speed of the scroll (points per second)
    @State private var offsetX: CGFloat = 0 // To move the buttons horizontally
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: spacing) {
            buttons
                .background {
                    
                    // Measure the width of one set of buttons and
                    // launch scrolling when the view appears
                    GeometryReader { proxy in
                        Color.clear
                            .onAppear {
                                startScrolling(scrolledWidth: proxy.size.width + spacing)
                            }
                            
                    }
                }
            
            // Repeat the buttons, so that the follow-on is seamless
            buttons
        }
        .offset(x: offsetX)
    }
    
    private var buttons: some View {
        HStack(spacing: spacing) {
            ForEach(Array(buttonItems.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { offset, item in
                Button {
                    // Button action
                } label: {
                    Text(item)
                        .padding(.vertical, 8)
                        .padding(.horizontal,15)
                        .fixedSize()
                        .foregroundStyle(Color("FontColor"))
                        .font(.system(size: 12))
                        .fontWeight(.light)
                        .background {
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                                .fill(Color.gray.opacity(colorScheme == .dark ? 0.15 : 0.05))
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func startScrolling(scrolledWidth: CGFloat) {
        withAnimation(
            .linear(duration: scrolledWidth / baseSpeed)
            .repeatForever(autoreverses: false)
        ) {
            offsetX = -scrolledWidth
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    QueryChipsView()
}


I have tried to bind the showSearchSheet variable to the QueryChipsView(animation) but unsuccessful, also adding onChange to the QueryChipsView components still unsuccessful.
Expected result: opening the sheet from SearchButtonView should not stop the animation of QueryChipsView
Actual result: opening of the sheet from SearchButtonView makes the animation in QueryChipsView stop and never start despite closing the sheet.
Question: is there a workaround or should the view be rebuild on sheet close?

Did you try applying .geometryGroup() to QueryChipsView, as I was suggesting in a previous comment? I am not able to reproduce the problem with the code provided here, there is too much missing (in particular, HeaderView, SearchButtonViewVModel and SearchView). When I use skeleton code to fill in the gaps, the animation still runs even after the sheet closes. But instead of posting even more code, can you perhaps try to reduce it, to turn it into a minimal reproducible example that is complete and runs in isolation?

So this question is a follow-up to your previous question, where I was suggesting that you run the animation with repeatForever instead of using a Timer.
Running on an iPhone 16 simulator with iOS 18.0 (and using skeleton code to fill the gaps for missing code), I can see that the animation jumps around when the sheet is shown. It helps to change the layout of the page so that the animation is in the top half, then apply .presentationDetents([.medium]) to the sheet content so that it doesn't go above half-height. However, with the improvised code, the animation seems to correct itself once the sheet is showing and also stays running when the sheet is dismissed.
Still, I do at least see that the animation is impacted when the sheet is shown.
I was also suggesting that you apply .geometryGroup() to the part of the view with the continuous animation, but when I tried this, it doesn't seem to help.
So I am wondering, if it might work better to go back to using a Timer, as you had it before? To try this, you just need to change the function startScrolling:
private func startScrolling(scrolledWidth: CGFloat) {
    let step = baseSpeed * 0.05
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.05, repeats: true) { timer in
        if abs(offsetX + scrolledWidth) < (step / 2) {
            offsetX += scrolledWidth // without animation
        }
        withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.1)) {
            offsetX -= step
        }
    }
}

Using this approach, I find that the animation is not quite as smooth as with the continuous repeating animation, but it doesn't get impacted by the sheet being shown.
If this helps, then a way of making the animation a bit smoother might be to compute the offset from the elapsed time, instead of always deducting the same step from the offset every time the timer fires. Also, you could consider moving the timer into the view model, so that the same timer can be used by all the scrolled rows. See this answer for a way of doing this.

Thanks for being such helpful. I tried with geometryGroup() and it's working. For now I think this is ok. For the new way of doing it and calculating the elapsed time, I will have to gain some exp. to be able to understand your new proposed solution.
